# tSQLt - Error 'Could not find method 'SigningKey' for type 'tSQLtCLR.tSQLtPrivate' in assembly 'tSQLtCLR''

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, redgate, tsqlt

We are moving Jenkins to a new server which has SQL Server 2019 installed.
Jenkins was previously running on a server that used SQL Server 2008 R2 (and the build process worked flawlessly)

We use Redgate's SQL Automation to perform a clean build of the database from our SVN repository

As part of this move it transpired that we needed to install the latest version of tSQLt and that is where we're running into problems.

I followed the advice (by Solomon Rutzky) given in this post:-
[Unable to create the tSQLtCLR assembly in SQL Server 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551132/unable-to-create-the-tsqltclr-assembly-in-sql-server-2017)

However, each time I try a build I'm seeing this message as the first warning:

> Invoke-DatabaseBuild, SQL Change Automation 4.0.19274.11021, Copyright ¶¸ Red Gate Software Ltd 2014-2019
>
> Cleaning database 'Blankdb' on server 'TTS-10\TTS2019'.
>
> Validating SQL Source Control project 'D:\Jenkins\workspace\Manzen Database Trunk'.
>
> WARNING: The error 'Could not find method 'SigningKey' for type 'tSQLtCLR.tSQLtPrivate' in assembly 'tSQLtCLR'' occurred when executing the following SQL:
>
> WARNING: CREATE FUNCTION [tSQLt].Info
>
> WARNING: RETURNS TABLE
>
> WARNING: AS
>
> WARNING: RETURN
>
> WARNING: SELECT Version = '1.0.5873.27393',
>
> WARNING:        ClrVersion = (SELECT tSQLt.Private::Info()),
>
> WARNING:        ClrSigningKey = (SELECT tSQLt.Private::SigningKey()),
>
> WARNING:        V.SqlVersion,
>
> WARNING:        V.SqlBuild,
>
> WARNING:        V.SqlEdition

... further code omitted for brevity

I'm into serious head scratching now as I can't figure out what I should have done.

I've seen reference in some posts online to dlls but don't see any on the new server after tSQLt has been installed.

I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this error:

1. You are building tSQLt yourself instead of using a published tSQLt build (--> use a published build)
2. Your tSQLt install file is corrupt. (--> download a new one)

If there is a legitimate reason to build tSQLt yourself, you need to replace the key with your own, as the original signing key is not published.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian.

I downloaded the tSQLt_V1.0.5873.27393.zip file and executed the tSQLt.class.sql file.


I didn't know you could build tSQLt yourself so it certainly isn't something I've tried to do.


Is the zip file the only file that needs to be downloaded?